# Webform Entity Checkboxes outputing its HTML in an odd manner

Tags: 8, forms, webforms

I have a medium sized web form composed mostly of standard web form elements and is using the Webform Module.

One of the items I have is a set of three Entity Check boxes which get their data from an Entity Reference view that returns only a title, e.g. "Rajasthan". Rajasthan is a node of a particular content type (Destination Detail)

The idea been the person filling out the form can choose one or more destinations by selecting the corresponding check box.

The problem I am having is that the check boxes display the title fine like

[image]

but if you inspect the HTML for the Rajasthan element is looks like this:

```
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-which-destination-asia-79" 
    class="form-checkbox" id="edit-which-destination-asia-79" 
    name="which_destination_asia[79]" value="79" type="checkbox">
```

Issues I am having trouble understanding:

1) Entity Check boxes belonging to the same group all have that number in the name, and other attributes but the number is different as it is the node id of that item. The problem here is in trying to PRE-set the default value for the correct item.

I did try put the Entity Check box element into a Fieldset element but this hasn't helped in any way.

2) Secondly the other issue is when the form is submitted, the admin get the node id returned which in a spreadsheet pretty much doesn't mean much to anyone other that me the developer.

I'd have thought that the Check box would have set the value to the title of the item returned from the Entity Reference, why is it using the node ID? I am not even returning that in the entity reference view

I have double checked the view, and it is returning only the textual title of the node which is correct and what I want to show as the value and check box text.

If the value of the check box was set to the actual title I think this would solve the pre-setting issue for me.

Many thanks
John

Comment: Different nodes can have the same title - if the form submission carried across the title, not the ID, how would the system be able to determine which node was selected?

Comment: @Clive, mm you have a point but in this case I know they will be different but that obviously doesn't change the fact that the system is built assuming what you just pointed out. Cheers, I'll have to find a way to transform the id after submission to something meaningful. Do I delete this question or leave it for others? i.e. is it helpful to leave it here or wasteful to keep it?

Comment: There's loads of hooks in webform.api.php, I'm sure one of those will let you get into the results and do a node load for the title to replace the id